# Pass associative Array to some other page in PHP

Tags: php, javascript

How can I pass an associative array to some other form through GET or POST?

Is there any way or do I need to convert it into a comma separated string first?

Answer (score 2):

If you mean passing a Javascript array into PHP, then the answer is to use [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON).

JSON is basically a string representation of a Javascript object structure. You can turn a Javascript object into a JSON string suitable for sending to the server using one of a number of libraries (modern browsers have a `.stringify()` method built in, but older browsers do not, so you'll need a library for this). JQuery is the obvious candidate, but there's plenty of others which will do the job. The actual technique will vary according to the library you use, so I won't try to post a code example here.

When you receive the string in PHP, you can use PHP's [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function to turn it into a PHP array.

Going in the opposite direction, you can encode a PHP array into a JSON string with `json_encode()`, and reading it into your Javascript should be fairly easy (again, modern browsers have the functionality build in; worst case you can simply `eval()` it, but that's risky, so I'd recommend again using a library for the task)

Even if one end of your process isn't Javascript, you can still use JSON, as virtually every language now has the ability to encode/decode JSON strings. You could do this, even if you're communicating between one PHP program and another.

If it *is* entirely a PHP->PHP communication, you could just as easily use `serialize()` and `unserialize()`, which produce a string format that looks different to JSON; for your purposes, it works in the same way, but it's a PHP-specific format, so JSON would generally be preferred.

Answer (score 1):

Convert it to an escaped JSON string is a good way of doing this. Take a look at `json_encode(object)`

Answer (score 0):

Using POST for example:

```
<form action="page.php" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="value1" value="1" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Will pass this to page.php

```
$_POST['value1'] // equals 1
```

As AJAX with jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    data: $('#form').serialize() // or [{key: 'value'}, {key: 'value2'}],
    url: 'page.php'
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change an array to a string using `serialize()`<sup>***[[docs]](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php)***</sup> and change it back using `unserialize()`<sup>***[[docs]](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php)***</sup> on the the string.